# How deploy React app to Heroku using port value from env?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, dotenv

Hi I was trying to deploy my rtmp server to Heroku but first I had some issues that I hard coded the ports instead of making env file. I use concurrently to run two scripts.
My file structure is

```
 rtmp-server
 ├── client
 └── rtmp
```

rtmp needs 2ports (1935 & 8888) & client need 2ports (3000 & 3001) as well

I have few questions.

1. Do I have to use Dotenv in **root** or in **subdirs** (client & rtmp both separately)
2. How can I use values of Dotenv in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` you could do something like *`command to serve $PORT`* to get the PORT variable

But there is a better way of handling this by reading the `PORT` variable in your code like so:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

Here 3000 is just the fallback value if `process.env.PORT` is `undefined`. This is useful while developing

Comment: I want at variable to package.json so should I put like this ```"server": "nodemon -p $SRV_PORT index.js" ```

Comment: Yes, that would do. But during development you probably don't need the hassle of setting an environment variable. **Dotenv variables are not read at this place**. It would work if you export(set) this variable in your terminal(with `export SRV_PORT=8080`) or specify the variables like so `SRV_PORT=8080 npm run server`, but for development you probably don't need this hassle as mentioned earlier